# Problema Jantar dos Canibais em Java

Tags: java

Estou fazendo um trabalho de faculdade na Threads e me encontrei em uma situação complicada que desde o começo da semana eu não resolvo hehehe

O problema é o Jantar dos Cannibais e estou desenvolvendo em Java. Eu realmente não gosto de códigos prontos, porque dificulta a aprendizagem.

Meu problema é este: os canibais não podem se servir ao mesmo tempo, mas eles podem comer ao mesmo tempo. Mas acho que aqui no meu, todos os threds estão aguardando o mesmo sleep () e o correto é que o THREAD CURRENT aguarde esse tempo.

A seguir estão as classes:

```
public class Caldeirao {
private int M;

public Caldeirao(int M) {
    this.M = M;
}

public int getM() {
    return M;
}

public void setM(int m) {
    M = m;
}
}
```

-

```
public class Canibal extends Thread {

private String nome;
private Caldeirao caldeirao;
private Cozinheiro cozinheiro;
private int qtdComidas = 0;

public Canibal(String nome, Caldeirao caldeirao, Cozinheiro cozinheiro) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.caldeirao = caldeirao;
    this.cozinheiro = cozinheiro;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    while (true) {

        try {
            this.cozinheiro.Servir(this);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public int getQtdComidas() {
    return qtdComidas;
}

public void setQtdComidas(int qtdComidas) {
    this.qtdComidas = qtdComidas;
}

}
```

-

```
public class Cozinheiro extends Thread {
private Caldeirao caldeirao;
private int qtdCaldeiraoComplete = 0;

public Cozinheiro(Caldeirao caldeirao) {
    this.caldeirao = caldeirao;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            preparaJantar();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

private synchronized void preparaJantar() throws InterruptedException {
    setQtdCaldeiraoComplete(this.getQtdCaldeiraoComplete() + 1);

    while (this.caldeirao.getM() > 0) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Cozinheiro acordado!");
    System.out.println("Cozinheiro preparando o jantar!");

    sleep(5000);

    this.caldeirao.setM(5);
    notify();
}

public synchronized void Servir(Canibal canibal) throws InterruptedException {
    notify();
    if (this.caldeirao.getM() > 0) {
        System.out.println("O canibal " + canibal.getNome() + " está se servindo!");
        Canibal.sleep(1000);
        this.caldeirao.setM(this.caldeirao.getM() - 1);
        Comer(canibal);
    } else {
        notify();
    }

}

public void Comer(Canibal canibal) {
    notify();
    System.out.println("O canibal " + canibal.getNome() + " está comendo!");
    canibal.setQtdComidas(canibal.getQtdComidas() + 1);
    try {
        Canibal.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public int getQtdCaldeiraoComplete() {
    return qtdCaldeiraoComplete;
}

public void setQtdCaldeiraoComplete(int qtdCaldeiraoComplete) {
    this.qtdCaldeiraoComplete = qtdCaldeiraoComplete;
}

}
```

-

```
public class Jantar {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Caldeirao caldeirao = new Caldeirao(5);

    Cozinheiro cozinheiro = new Cozinheiro(caldeirao);

    Canibal canibal1 = new Canibal("#1", caldeirao, cozinheiro);
    Canibal canibal2 = new Canibal("#2", caldeirao, cozinheiro);
    Canibal canibal3 = new Canibal("#3", caldeirao, cozinheiro);

    cozinheiro.start();

    canibal1.start();
    canibal2.start();
    canibal3.start();

    long inicial = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - inicial) <= 120000) {
    }

    cozinheiro.stop();

    canibal1.stop();
    canibal2.stop();
    canibal3.stop();

    System.out.println("O cozinheiro encheu o caldeirao " + cozinheiro.getQtdCaldeiraoComplete());

    System.out.println("O canibal " + canibal1.getNome() + " comeu " + canibal1.getQtdComidas() + " vezes");
    System.out.println("O canibal " + canibal2.getNome() + " comeu " + canibal2.getQtdComidas() + " vezes");
    System.out.println("O canibal " + canibal3.getNome() + " comeu " + canibal3.getQtdComidas() + " vezes");

}

}
```

Minha duração de 2 minutos está saindo:

O cozinheiro encheu a caldeira 4 O canibal # 1 comeu 9 vezes O canibal # 2 comeu 5 vezes O canibal # 3 comeu 11 vezes

Meu professor disse que a média estava entre 18 e 20 anos.

Alguém teria alguma ideia? Desde já, obrigado! : D

Answer (score 0):

Se você não quer que seja executado ao mesmo tempo a ação "servir" então este não deverá ser sincronizado. No caso o trecho abaixo deve ser modificado pelo método a seguir..

```
public synchronized void Servir(Canibal canibal) throws InterruptedException {
    notify();
    if (this.caldeirao.getM() > 0) {
        System.out.println("O canibal " + canibal.getNome() + " está se servindo!");
        Canibal.sleep(1000);
        this.caldeirao.setM(this.caldeirao.getM() - 1);
        Comer(canibal);
    } else {
        notify();
    }
}
```

Por este:

```
public void Servir(Canibal canibal) throws InterruptedException {
    notify();
    if (this.caldeirao.getM() > 0) {
        System.out.println("O canibal " + canibal.getNome() + " está se servindo!");
        Canibal.sleep(1000);
        this.caldeirao.setM(this.caldeirao.getM() - 1);
        Comer(canibal);
    } else {
        notify();
    }
}
```

Desta forma, as threads quando consumirem este cara, vão aguardar executar um por vez, como uma espécie de fila.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Pois é, já tentei. Quando eu troco, ele me dá o seguinte erro: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

Comment: Experimenta separar o método servir em uma nova classe, e instancie ele depois, considere o uso de um singleton.

Comment: É, tá dando certo não. Vou continuar testando aqui durante a noite toda. Deve ser uma besteira que eu não esteja notificando. Porque TODOS os processos estão esperando o sleep e não um só. Obrigado mesmo assim! :D

Comment: Certo, e não tenho como rodar isso agora, mas a noite vou tentar um tempinho e rodar isso e te ajudar. :)

Comment: Poxa cara, muito obrigado! De verdade :) Vou ficar aqui de plantão até amanhã a hora de apresentar o trabalho hehehe :D